# .htaccess - Add random text after url

Tags: .htaccess

i make a .htaccess that can add ?example  after the url 
(site.com/page1?EXAMPLE)

but i like to add random numbers or letters there
(site.com/page1?jsf6755saf)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)EXAMPLE(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}?EXAMPLE [L,QSA,R=302,NE]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

how i can make this

Comment: Please read [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) before asking this question again.

Answer (score 2):

Change your first rule to:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}?%{TIME} [L,R=302,NE]
```

Which in other words means that if `QUERY_STRING` doesn't already exist then add `%{TIME}` value in it.

Comment: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)EXAMPLE(&|$) [NC]`
   `RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}?EXAMPLE [L,QSA,R=302,NE]`


how to make this so it will not add ?example   but ?random text

Comment: Didn't understand it. Did you try adding any random text with the rule I provided here?

Comment: so this .httaccess  that i posted in first post  add ?example   at end of url
so url of my site will be   site.com/page23?example
i like not to add (?example)  at end of urls  but to add a random text   like this      site.com/page23?AafFsd254dsf

Comment: You can add `site.com/page23?AafFsd254dsf` with above rule. Did you get any error with `site.com/page23?AafFsd254dsf` URL?

Comment: can u tell me what to add in .htaccess  so it will have rondom text after "?"

Comment: You just need to replace your `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)EXAMPLE(&|$) [NC]` with the `RewriteCond` I provided in answer above

Comment: you are not understeanding me
- i need a htaccess that will add a random text at end of url
so if my page is  
page1.com/1.html   it will add ?RANDOM TEXT    after that

www.page1.com/1.html?234nsdfslkf

Answer (score 2):

Only NOTE to the 1st answer by : Panama Jack - SO MUCH THANK YOU.

- **RewriteMap servers rnd:/path/to/file/map.txt**

  DO NOT put it in .htaccess file ( it will generate internal error ).

  PLACE IT ONLY in one of your *.conf (e.g apache2.conf).
- 
- **Replace %{servers:random} with ${servers:random}**

  ONLY THEN - it worked for me.

  Documentation source :  https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html#rnd

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have to use something like RewriteMap to provide random text in Apache.

**That is about the only way if you want to control the the text that is put there.**

There is a **MapType rnd** that can pull random text into a variable.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap

Here is an example of usage. 
Create a text file with this structure and put random strings piped together.

Contents of map.txt

```
##
##  map.txt -- rewriting map
##

random  r3434fd|ssfsfs334|3542tgwet|w34rf235|32gvsr3|345343r|35fgew54e|bff534!q
```

**NOTE: This is not a complete rule. Just an example to show you how to use the random variable.** Just append your rule with `%{servers:random}`

```
RewriteMap servers rnd:/path/to/file/map.txt

RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}?%{servers:random} [L,QSA,R=302,NE]
```

Apache will then randomly pull one of those strings from map.txt to use in your query string that you want.

If you just want random text.

**You can also use the `UNIQUE_ID`**

```
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}?%{UNIQUE_ID} [L,QSA,R=302,NE]
```

It will put out something like `qOr5tEBvcm8AAE-VoiUAAAAQ`

Comment: Make sure you enable the module. mod_unique_id. That could cause the error. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_unique_id.html